# What is the difference between a mapreduce application and a yarn application?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

A cluster which runs mapreduce 2 doesn't have a job tracker and instead it is split into two separate components, resource manager and job manager. However, these thing are transparent from a user and he doesn't need to know whether the cluster is running mapreduce 1 or 2 when submitting a mapreduce job.

The thing I cannot quite understand is Yarn application. How is it different from a regular mapreduce application? What's the advantage of running a mapreduce job as a yarn application, etc? Could someone shed some light on that for me?

Answer (score 0):

MR1 has Job tracker and task tracker which takes care of Map reduce application.

In MR2 Apache separated the management of the map/reduce process from the cluster's resource management by using YARN. YARN is a better resource manger than we had in MR1. It also enables versatility. MR2 is built on top of YARN.

**Apart from Map reduce, we can run applications like spark, storm, Hbase, Tex etc on top of Yarn, which we cannot do using MR1.**

The following is the architecture for MR1 and MR2.

```
HDFS <---> MR

HDFS <----> Yarn <----> MR
```

Comment: Thanks, but I actually have a different question. I'm aware of the architecture of the MR2, my question is I can run the same piece of code on both MR1 and MR2. In the former case, there is a job and task tracker and in the latter one there is Yarn managing things but when I need to develop a Yarn application? (what I mean by Yarn application is an application using java package org.apache.hadoop.yarn)

Comment: Because in MR1 job tracker has to handle all the pressure. The total jobs capacity in MR1 is nearly 4000. But MR2 it is more this figures.  Job tracker has to handle all the pressure in mr1. in yarn Resource manager job is to jyst schedule and allocate resource and the job monitoring and running will be taken care by per application master for a job.

Comment: so when to develop application using package org.apache.hadoop.yarn?

Comment: one more scenario is if job tracker goes down, all jobs in Mr1 will be hanged. But if resource manager fails , all the current jobs wont get killed. cluster cant accept the new jobs, but the existing jobs will be under the supervision of applicationmaster and if has enough resources and runs and sends the output.

Comment: Its your call. if your application just needs Mapreduce , you can use MR1 or MR2. if you want to use applications like HBase, Strom etc go with Yarn. Yarn is always a better option because of its resource management